# How to escape { and } in heredoc PHP

Tags: php, escaping, heredoc

I want to use { in a string which is being stored in heredoc in PHP, how to use it? how to escape?

```
echo $heredoc = <<<HTML
<p>
    Welcome {$myname}
</p>
HTML;
```

The output is `Welcome Aayush Sinha`

But the output required is `Welcome {Aayush Sinha}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap it around another pair of curly braces

```
echo $heredoc = <<<HTML
<p>
     Welcome {{$myname}}
</p>
HTML;
```

That will do the job.

Output: `Welcome {Aayush Sinha}`.